# Are Wifi-Network data/credentials stored even when we forget it?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, command-line, windows-registry

Does Windows store Wifi-credentials even when we forget it?

I'm concerned about my Wifi-Network which I shared with a friend who is a real computer geek. Can he access the wifi password even when I forget my network from his device.

Is it stored in Windows Registry? Or can he access it from command prompt.

I tried this.

```
netsh wlan show profile %ssid% key=clear
```

Maybe command prompt doesn't show ssid and password after forgetting, but I am not sure of Windows Registry.

P.S.: I don't wan't to change the Wifi-Router password for some reason.

Comment: Note that  `%ssid%` is a variable I set using `set /p` in a batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there're two ways you can check:

1.Search **Crendential Manager** in windows and you will see the Crendentials stored.

2.Type in the following CMD command, It’ll show the WiFi networks it has saved passwords for.

**netsh wlan show profiles**

To delete a wireless network profile in Windows 10:
(1)Click the Network icon on the lower right corner of your screen.
Click Network settings.
Click Manage Wi-Fi settings.
Under Manage known networks, click the network you want to delete.
Click Forget. The wireless network profile is deleted.

(2)Or Type the following command:

**netsh wlan delete profile “PROFILE NAME”**
(Replace the “Profile Name” with the name of the Wi-Fi network you want to erase.)